# How to get the current highest supported TLS version in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2, windows-server-2019, tls1.3

My application downloads the resources from different sources but now I am facing the problem that some of the servers only support TLS 1.3 and request server does not have support of TLS 1.3 (windows server 2019) so what I am thinking is to add the condition in my program such that to check the supported TLS version first and then fire those request only.
e.g.

```
if(SupportedMaxTLSVersion == Tls13)
{
  // call TLS 1.3 specific request
}
else
{
  // TLS 1.2 or older version requests
}
```

In this way I can use the same application on 2 different servers, one which does not have support of TLS 1.3 like Windows server 2019 and one on windows server 2022 which has the support.

Note - .NET version of the application is 4.6.2

is there any way to achieve this?

Tried to put some conditions in code and tried in server 2019 which did not work.

Comment: "some of the servers only support TLS 1.3" sounds like a bad idea as there are many many systems and firewalls that only support TLS 1.2

Answer (score 0):

For supporting TLS 1.3, the target .NET Framework should be 4.8 or later.

If you have a proper version, you can get the supported TLS versions by:

```cs
SslProtocols supportedProtocols = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol;

if (supportedProtocols.HasFlag(SslProtocols.Tls13))
{
    // call TLS 1.3 specific request
}
else
{
  // TLS 1.2 or older version requests
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `(supportedProtocols & SslProtocols.Tls13) == targetProtocol)` be `(supportedProtocols & SslProtocols.Tls13) == SslProtocols.Tls13)`?

Comment: @phuzi Right, fixed that. Thank you!

Comment: Or even better `supportedProtocols.HasFlaq(SslProtocols.Tls13)`? sorry

Comment: @Misha I think your code has some problem, is it not suppose to be -
SecurityProtocolType supportedProtocols = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol; 
?? or do we need to explicitly cast it

Comment: @sarawgeek I updated it according to phuzi recommendation. Can you check again please?

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky This code is not working for me, I am using .net version 4.6.2.

Comment: @sarawgeek Ohhh I missed it. .NET 4.6.2 does not support TLS 1.3 by default. You should upgrade your .NET version if you want to support TLS 1.3.

Comment: @sarawgeek I updated my answer and specified which version you should upgrade to.

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky 2 things- do you need to explicit cast it to SslProtocols? Second is if I change the framework to 4.8 then this line - ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol only returns "SystemDefault", so if condition is not working in that case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253313/discussion-between-sarawgeek-and-misha-zaslavsky).